# Django ORM with PostgreSQL return wrong data using icontains

Tags: django, database, postgresql, ubuntu

My model is.

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    supplierId = models.IntegerField('Supplier ID', primary_key=True)
    supplierName = models.CharField('Поставщик', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    inn = models.CharField('ИНН', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    ogrn = models.CharField('ОГРН', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    legalAddress = models.CharField('Юридический адрес', max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have 2 records with the same supplierName='Смирнова Ольга Александровна'.

```
sellers = Seller.objects.filter(supplierName__icontains='Смирнова Ольга Александровна')
print(sellers.count()) # return 1
sellers = Seller.objects.filter(supplierName__contains='Смирнова Ольга Александровна')
print(sellers.count()) # return 2
sellers = Seller.objects.filter(supplierName='Смирнова Ольга Александровна')
print(sellers.count()) # return 2
```

I also try to use supplierName__search, but it returns not normal data too.
icontains return wrong data not only in this example.

I tried to create same postgresql database on my local windows computer with the same model and records in it. And it works correctly. Database with problem is working on ubuntu 20.04

What can i do with it? I need this for correct search on my site.

Comment: Likely you have set the wrong collation settings for your database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you! The problem was in collation settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in collation settings

Im delete and create again postgresql cluster with new collation. Without creating a cluster, he did not see the russian encoding.

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales 
# install your locales
pg_dropcluster --stop 14 main 
# It will delete your cluster with all data, so backup it before
pg_createcluster --locale ru_RU.UTF-8 --start 14 main
# 14 - your postgres veriosn, main - your cluster name (main by default)
```

**Also you can change db_collation for field in django, if locale presents in psql \l**